# Interactive bins Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for help to solve my problem.
I need to make bins out out of 'Escalão' - however the bins size depends on the product / Master A and Zona.
Is there a way to change the bins depending on the other column values?
Like this :
[image]

What I want is that everytime the 'Produto' changes the 'cut' would change too - creating new bins ( that are based on 'Escalão' )  and the labels would be the rightest value of the Bin.

The code I have right now is for normal binning :

```
All = pd.toDataFrame({'Master Agreement':['200011706.0'];'Zona':['1'];'Escalão':['200','300','900','100','120','240'];'Peso Total':['233.830';'343.977','507.750','400','230','110']})

Bins = [0,200,300,900]
Labels = ['200','300','900','+']
All['Escalão de Peso dos Envios_Antigamente' ] = pd.cut(All['Escalão'].astype(float), Bins, labels=Labels)
```

Comment: Hi! You're more likely to get an answer if you include your 6-row dataframe as python code such as `df = pd.DataFrame({'Master': [...], 'Zona': [...], ...})`; so that potential answerers can play around with your dataframe easily.

Comment: How do you want to create bins? What are you actually asking?

Comment: Hi @Stef thank you, I added it !

Comment: Hi @MadPhysicist , I want the bins created based on 'Escalão' - the bins should then see where 'Peso Total' falls inside. However I need the bins to be different each time there is a new product or master agreement or Zona. This because 'Escalão' is a function of this 3 categories.

Comment: It looks like you probably want some combination of groupby and pd.cut. Didn't really fully understand your question to comment further.

Comment: @SMeznaric Hey Guys thank you for trying to help - I tried to explain it better with a new image... does it help at all? Basically what I want is that the 'Bins' values (edges) match with 'Escalão' values.